# Select list move down

Tags: php, javascript, html, web

I'm developing a webpage with a select list that contains images.
I already have this:

When I select an image name in the list the image will be displayed in the div below.

```
<?php 
   // Create connection
   $con=mysqli_connect("******","***","***","charts");

   // Check connection
   if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
   {
       echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
   }
?>

<form method="post" action="index.php" id="nano" name="nano">
  <p>
  <select name="SelectBox" id="SelectBox"  onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <?php if($_POST['submitted'] == true){ ?>
    <?php 
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Nano WHERE IMAGE_NAME ='". $_POST['SelectBox']."'");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    { ?> 
    <option selected="selected" value="<?php  echo $row['IMAGE_NAME'] ?>">
      <?php  echo $row['IMAGE_PARAMETER'] ?>
      </option>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php echo $_POST['SelectBox']; ?></option>
    <?php } else{ ?>

    <?php 
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT TOP * FROM Nano");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
    ?> 
    <option selected="selected" value="<?php  echo $row['IMAGE_NAME'] ?>">
      <?php  echo $row['IMAGE_PARAMETER'] ?>
          </option>
      <?php  
          $var1 = $row['IMAGE_NAME']; ?>
      <?php
    }
    ?>

    <?php } ?>
    <option value="" disabled="disabled"> -------- </option>
    <?php

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Nano");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  { $values[] =  $row['IMAGE_NAME'];

?>
    <option value="<?php  echo $row['IMAGE_NAME'] ?>">
      <?php  echo $row['IMAGE_PARAMETER'] ?>
      </option>
    <?php }?>
  </select>
  <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true" />
  </p>
<?php if($_POST['submitted'] == true){ ?>
  <p><img src="Images\Nano\<?php echo $_POST['SelectBox']?>" width="953" height="600" /></p>
<?php }else { ?>
<p><img src="Images\Nano\<?php print_r($values[0]) ?>" width="953" height="600" /></p>
<?php  } mysqli_close($con);?>
</form>
</div>
```

I want when I move down in the select list the picture will change and not when I click on it in the select list.

Comment: I see no javascript code.

Comment: `onChange` or its jQuery equivalent

Comment: do you really need to submit the form when the select value changes? can't you just update the src of the img using javascript?

Comment: No i don't need the submit i just want a select list withn images names from a database. when i scroll down the list the images must change and displayed below the select list

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you have to bind `hover` event to `option`, but there is no way to do what you want using native `select` control. The native one only answers when you click a different `option` from previous.

However, you can simulate a `select` control using html&css&js, that way when your cursor move down the simulated `option`(which might be a div or something), you can bind event handlers to it and display the name.